# How to retrieve data cached using Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app where I fetch posts on my main list and store them in Room, more specifically, in a Post table.

To get the posts from my main list I can't get all the posts from my Post table as there are other points in the application from which posts are fetched and stored, such as a post search listing.

I would like to know how to handle my problem, I am open to hearing any opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mark posts fetched for main list.

Suppose the post model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "`YOUR_TABLE`")
internal data class PostEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_main")
    val isMain: Boolean, // true means that post was fetched for main list
    ...
)
```

And you should write the [query request](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query) to the Room.

For example:

```
@Query(
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM `YOUR_TABLE` " +
        "WHERE post.is_main = 1"
    )
    suspend fun getMainListPosts(): List<PostEntity>
```

Comment: In that case, what would happen if on the search page, fetch a post that is already in the main list? How it would be stored?

Comment: did you see my last comment?